# Passing objects from server to android

Tags: java, android, web-services, server

I have a Java servlet web server and an android application that communicate with each other. What is the proper way of passing a custom object (EX: User object) from server to android.

Example:
User logs in through android device, the users email and password are sent to the server for authentication. Server now needs to send back to the android device the User object.

If you can attach an example or link to tutorial that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gyaay7OTy-w

make a class that extends AsyncTask
implement override methods (Alt+Insert)
In do in background:
Make an http url connection

```
try {
            URL url=new URL(urladdress);


            HttpURLConnection con= (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setRequestMethod("POST")
            con.setDoOutput(true);

            con.setDoInput(true);
            return con;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

now download the data from this connection

```
if(con==null) {
            Toast.makeText(ctx,"Connection is null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }

    try{
        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        String line;
        StringBuffer jsonData= new StringBuffer();

        while ((line=br.readLine())!=null)
        {

            jsonData.append(line+"/n");
        }
        br.close();
        is.close();
        return jsonData.toString();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

now parse this jsonData

```
try{

            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(jsonData);
            JSONObject jo = null;
            //parse Data

            }
```

In onPostExecute call the required java file which will receive data
write a script that convert data recived from your server and send data in json format

Note- these code belongs three different classes so don't try copy/paste

Answer (score 1):

Use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), is quite simple and straightforward.

Retrofit has given almost all the API's to make server call and to receive response. Internally they also use GSON to do the parsing. you can go through the official website you will get more info and a tutorial.

Hope it helps